# LEFT JOIN doesn't return all values

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, left-join, where-clause

I have the following tables:

```
create table Cars
(
  CarID int,
  CarType varchar(50)
);


create table Maintenances
(
  CarID int,
  MaintenanceDate date,
  MaintenanceCost money
);

create table Repairs
(
  CarID int,
  RepairDate date,
  RepairCost money
);
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT C.CarType,
SUM(MaintenanceCost),
SUM(RepairCost)
FROM Cars AS C 
LEFT JOIN Maintenances AS M ON M.CarID=C.CarID
LEFT JOIN Repairs AS R ON R.CarID=C.CarID
WHERE M.MaintenanceDate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31' AND
R.RepairDate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY C.CarType
```

But it doesn't return values for all the CarType. See this fiddle: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a5a1d8a8528dae5f7c88b545d2daddc)

Comment: Your `WHERE` is turning your outer joins into inner joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the conditions on the `LEFT JOIN`ed tables from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the joins - otherwise, they become mandatory, and non-matching rows in either table are filtered out.

So:

```
SELECT C.CarType, SUM(M.MaintenanceCost), SUM(R.RepairCost)
FROM Cars AS C 
LEFT JOIN Maintenances M 
    ON  M.CarID = C.CarID 
    AND M.MaintenanceDate BETWEEN '20201201' AND '20201231'
LEFT JOIN Repairs R 
    ON  R.CarID = C.CarID 
    AND R.RepairDate BETWEEN '20201201' AND '20201231'
GROUP BY C.CarType
```

Side notes:

- I prefixed the columns in the `SUM()` with the table they belong to (I had to make a guess): this is good practice, and makes the query self-explanatory, and unambiguous
- `YYYYMMDD` is supported in all versions of SQL Server as a date literal, regardless of regional settings, so it might be a better choice than `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are filtering by the date of the Maintenance and Repairs table. Only CarID 3 has an entry for your given date range in both the tables.

You can try this query if you want your result to include all car types for your date range.

```
    SELECT C.CarType,
    ISNULL(SUM(MaintenanceCost),0) AS MaintenanceCost,
    ISNULL(SUM(RepairCost),0) AS RepairCost
     Cars AS C 
     JOIN Maintenances AS M 
       M.CarID = C.CarID
       M.MaintenanceDate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'
     JOIN Repairs AS R 
       R.CarID = C.CarID
       R.RepairDate BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'
     BY C.CarType
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `SUM()`s to be correct, I would suggest writing this logic using correlated subqueries.  The problem is that you end up with a Cartesian Product for each `Carid` -- and that Cartesian Product means the sum is calculated in correctly:

If `CarType` is unique in `Cars`, you can use:

```
SELECT C.CarType,
       (SELECT SUM(M.MaintenanceCost)
        FROM Maintenances M 
        WHERE M.CarID = C.CarID AND
              M.MaintenanceDate BETWEEN '20201201' AND '20201231' 
       ),
       (SELECT SUM(R.RepairCost)
        FROM Repairs R
        WHERE R.CarID = R.CarID AND
              R.RepairDate BETWEEN '20201201' AND '20201231' 
       )
FROM Cars C ;
```

Otherwise, this looks a bit more complicated, because you need `CarType` in each subquery:

```
SELECT C.CarType,
       (SELECT SUM(M.MaintenanceCost)
        FROM Maintenances M JOIN
             Cars C
             ON M.CarID = C.CarID
        WHERE C.CarType = CT.CarType AND
              M.MaintenanceDate BETWEEN '20201201' AND '20201231' 
       ),
       (SELECT SUM(R.RepairCost)
        FROM Repairs R JOIN
             Cars C
             ON R.CarID = C.CarID
        WHERE C.CarType = CT.CarType AND
              R.RepairDate BETWEEN '20201201' AND '20201231' 
       )
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CarType FROM Cars C) CT
```